# Display rationale for location services

Tags: android, kotlin, android-jetpack-compose

I'd like to display for user a rationale, that is similar to one whenever we ask for location permissions (use precise/approximate location), but instead of permissions, I'd like to ask for location services this time. How I can make it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

- Check if location services are enabled.
- If location services are not enabled, display a rationale explaining
  why they are necessary.
- Provide an option for the user to enable location services through
  settings.

  ```
   object LocationUtils {
   fun checkLocationServices(activity: Activity) {
       val locationManager = activity.getSystemService(Context.LOCATION_SERVICE) as LocationManager
       if (!locationManager.isProviderEnabled(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER)) {
           showLocationServicesRationale(activity)
       }
   }

   private fun showLocationServicesRationale(activity: Activity) {
       val dialogBuilder = AlertDialog.Builder(activity)
       dialogBuilder.setTitle("Location Services Required")
       dialogBuilder.setMessage("Location services are required to use this feature. Please enable location services.")
       dialogBuilder.setPositiveButton("Enable") { dialog, which ->
           // Open settings to enable location services
           val settingsIntent = Intent(Settings.ACTION_LOCATION_SOURCE_SETTINGS)
           activity.startActivity(settingsIntent)
       }
       dialogBuilder.setNegativeButton("Cancel") { dialog, which ->
           // Handle cancellation if needed
       }
       dialogBuilder.setOnCancelListener {
           // Handle cancellation if the dialog is canceled
       }
       dialogBuilder.show()
   }
  ```

  }

This code will display a rationale to the user if location services are not enabled, asking them to enable it. If the user chooses to enable it, the settings screen for location services will be opened. If they choose to cancel, you can handle that in the code accordingly.